# Is GitHub's dependency graph user customizable?

Tags: node.js, github, monorepo, degit

I use degit to pull data partially from a monorepo. As the repo is not described in package.json it doesn't show up in dependency graph. Is there any technique to show it up, like customizing graph manually? I need it for managing my repos.